# Array point 0 doesn't reset content

Tags: c, arrays

I've made use of an array, and want to delete the content by placing null in array[0] but it doesn't work. Example... If I type Jesper, then the serial.print(nameBuffer[1]) returns e.

A temporary solution I use is a for-loop to place null in all it's spaces.

```
char name1[9] = "Jesper";
char nameBuffer[9];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{    

int i = 0;
nameBuffer[0] = 0;
Serial.print(nameBuffer[1]);
Serial.println("  All reset\n");

while(Serial.available() == 0)
{
    // wait for data to be send
}

while(Serial.available() > 0)
{
    int inByte = Serial.read();
    delay(50);
    nameBuffer[i] = char(inByte);
    i++;
    Serial.print("Recieved bytes: ");
    Serial.println(inByte,DEC);
}
  Serial.print("Searching for: "); 
  Serial.println(nameBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Please add what language you are using

Comment: Kindly mention which language you are using?
Why array point 0 should reset the whole content of the array ?
The reset at array[0] will reset the value only at that location

Comment: why do you think that setting `nameBuffer[0]` will affect what's in `nameBuffer[1]`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I gave myself the idea that array[0] = 0 would clear the whole array, but I've found that the problem is solved with memset and/or for-loops.

Comment: The 'cast' notation `nameBuffer[i] = char(inByte);` is valid in C++, but not in C.  Are you sure you know which language you're working in?  At the least, if that code compiles, you must be using a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`nameBuffer` is an array of 9 `char` elements. Each of those elements has a value of type `char`.

Setting a `char` object to 0 doesn't *remove* it from the array (`0` or `'\0'`, the null character, is as valid a `char` value as any other), nor does it affect the elements that follow it.

Now if you're treating the contents of `nameBuffer` as a *string* (defined by the C standard as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character"), then storing `'\0'` in `nameBuffer[0]` will cause it to contain an *empty string*. It has a *length* of 0, but there are still 9 `char` values stored in the array. So this:

```
printf("%s", nameBuffer);
```

won't print anything, but `namebuffer[1]` is still a valid `char` object holding whatever value was last stored in it.

Don't assume that printing a null character, or sending it over a serial port, will do nothing. If you don't want to print each character in your array, you'll need some logic to avoid printing the characters you don't want.

Incidentally, your code appears to be C++, not C. You have overloaded versions of `Serial.print`, one taking a `char` argument and one taking a `char*`; C doesn't support overloading. And `char(inByte)` is C++; it's a syntax error in C. (BTW, a cast isn't necessary there; the value will be converted implicitly.)